# File not getting uploaded using java.awt.Robot class in Java

Tags: java, selenium, awtrobot

I tried implementing Robot class in my Selenium Test cases written using Java. I am getting a strange issue there. So when I am trying to run those test cases on my local machine (Windows 10 Enterprise Edition) and monitoring it's working fine and the file is getting uploaded. But when I am trying to run those in a remote server (Windows Server 2012) and monitoring those it's again working fine but when I am leaving those test cases for the entire night to run I found that the **File Explorer** dialogue box is opening but it's never getting close. It might be that the file path is not getting pasted and the Enter (Ok) button is not getting clicked.

```
    public void uploadFile(String path) {
        String abspath = _getAbsolutePath(path);
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(abspath);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
        Robot robot = null;
        try {
            // native key strokes for CTRL, V and ENTER keys
            robot = new Robot();
            robot.setAutoDelay(5000);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); // Press Ctrl
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V); // Pres V

            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V); // Release Ctrl
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); // Release V

            robot.setAutoDelay(5000);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); // Press Enter
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); // Release Enter
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```